# AngularJS - md-cols-xl is the same as md-cols-gt-md - should be > not >=

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

**Actual Behavior**:

- `What is the issue? *`  If screen width is greater than or **equal**
  to 1920px (1920px and up - same as gt-md? why?)
- `What is the expected behavior?` If screen width is **greater** than 1920px (1921px and up)

---

**CodePen**:

- `CodePen Demo which shows your issue:`
  http://codepen.io/initPRAGMA/pen/dNyKLM
- `Details:` As you can see, I set col-gt-md to show 6 for 1920px size screens (md-cols-gt-md), and 12 for anything bigger than 1920px screens (md-cols-xl - Which should be > 1920px not >= 1920px). Because its >= 1920px it also shows 12 for <1920px screens but I need it to show 12 for anything ABOVE 1920px.

---

**Angular Versions**: *

- `Angular Version:` 1.5.8
- `Angular Material Version:` 1.1.1

---

**Additional Information**:

- `Browser Type: *` Chrome
- `Browser Version: *` 55.0.2883.87
- `OS: *` Windows 10
- `Stack Traces:` n/a

---

Is there any way to force-fix this? Im basically trying to get 2560x1080 screens to be 12 per row, and for 1920x1080 screens to be 6 per row.

The obvious idea would be to do my own MediaQuery CSS, but I have no idea how it works for md-cols-* property. I also cant find the current ones anywhere so im assuming its actually parsed using JS instead of CSS. Otherwise I would have already done this to fix the issue.

Comment: can always add your own css override rule(s)

Comment: @charlietfl I have no idea how to add the md-col breakpoint rules though.

Comment: copy the existing ones and adjust

Comment: @charlietfl thats what im saying, I cant find the breakpoints for md-cols anywhere.

Comment: Still need help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwite that breakpoint on a global level by setting this:

`$mdConstant.MEDIA.xl = '(min-width: 1921px)';`.

Simply inject `$mdConstant` into `angular.config` and set it. It is provided by angular-material.

See https://github.com/angular/material/blob/v1.1.1/src/core/util/constant.js

Comment: How do I actually turn this into a .js that I can use? do I simply add the constant.js to my HEAD tags under my reference to AngularJS?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Having trouble getting it to actually use mdConstant
`var titledbApp = angular.module('titledbApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngCookies']);
titledbApp.config(['$mdConstant', function ($mdConstant) { $mdConstant.MEDIA.xl = '(min-width: 1921px)'; }]);
`

Comment: Try it in a `angular.run` then, I have to admit, I only tried it in your example controller.